# Zxing scanner´s stop and restart

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have integrated Zxing QR scanner in my app. I need app to stop scanning when scanner reads a code. How can I stop the scanning? Because when a QR is scanned the scanner continues reading and not stops. I want that the scanner stop after read a QR and later with a button click restart the scanner to continue reading codes. Thank  you.

```
public class SampleFragment extends BarCodeScannerFragment {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setmCallBack(new IResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void result(Result lastResult) {
                String id = lastResult.toString();

                TextView mitext = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                mitext.setText(id);
            }
        });
    }

    public SampleFragment() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just start activity for result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and then process the results in `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // process results
}
```

**Edit:**

Have you tried using `stopScan()` and `startScan()` from: https://github.com/welcu/zxingfragmentlib/blob/master/library/src/com/welcu/android/zxingfragmentlib/BarCodeScannerFragment.java ?

Comment: I can´t, I´m my app I have to do the Scanner activity in the same activity that I get the result. Some other idea? Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code (especially your scanner activity)?

Comment: Yes, but if I use stopScan() the screen turns black, is possible to not scan but the camera goes on? Thanks